# How to clip a pattern overlay to a transparent shape

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, patterns

I want to use this design on a shirt but can not figure out how to just have the dots clip to the shape without having a fill color.

So basically I want the fill color gone and the dot pattern to still exist.

[image: T Shirt Design]

Comment: Not enough info... how are the dots applied? Is it a pattern overly? A fill pattern? A Pattern layer? Is it the white you are trying to remove? Is this for actual silk screening or printing press (then white doesn't matter).

Comment: @Scott The dots are applied as a Pattern Overlay. I am trying to remove the white.

Answer (score 1):

If this is for print production, the white is irrelevant and can remain without any issues. White = stock (paper) in print.

In any event to remove the background fill of the shape when a pattern overly is applied, simply reduce the **Fill Opacity** to **0%** for that layer.

[image]

Of course, this assume the white is not actually *part of the pattern* used in the overlay. If the white *is* part of the pattern, you need to recreate the pattern without the background.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using illustrator, expand the fill, it should give you the circles and the white background. if you're in photoshop use multiply it will get rid of the white. if you export the picture as png it should only have the dots with the transparency